# The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /test.txt

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, http-status-code-405

I have setup the apache httpd server using below command

```
yum install httpd
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd
```

it started, when i try to upload file using below Curl command it's throwing error

`curl --upload-file /tmp/test.txt http://127.0.0.1:80`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /test.txt.</p>
</body></html>
```

as per httpd.conf file configuration test.txt should be uploaded to var/www/html location.

Comment: you need to enable a handler that allows such thing. By default httpd will not obviously allow you to upload files. Check mod_dav.